# Combining sentences with “who”

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I have to combine sentences in many ways. 
Could you help me check them please?

1. I was sitting on the bridge.
2. I watched the children.

I think it is okay to combine sentences like this.

Watching the children, I was sitting on the bridge,

But is it possible if I use “who” like the sentence below?

I, **who** watched the children, was sitting on the bridge.

I'm not sure that "who" can be after personal pronoun or not.

Comment: I believe you could say that if that's what you mean (what you do is taking care of children day in and day out). I mean you would agree that saying *"I, who watched the children, was sitting on the bridge,"* is not the same thing as, *"I, who was watching the children, was sitting on the bridge"*. Anyway, combining them with *while* might sound better, imho.

Comment: Many thanks Damkerng T. I agree with you on "while" but I 'd like to know about the possibility of using “who” after a personal pronoun.

Comment: I sat on the bridge watching the children

Comment: "As I was sitting on the bridge, I watched the children" "I, who watched the children, while/whilst sitting on the bridge." Is possible... But my instinct says to rephrase the entire sentence to: While I was sitting on the bridge; the children, who I was looking after, were playing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but unusual.

According to *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan,

> **498 relatives (5): advanced points**
>   **12 agreement of person**
>   Most relative clauses have third-person reference; *I who ...* , *you who ...* and *we who ...* are unusual, though they sometimes occur in a very formal style.
>   
>   ***You who*** pass by, tell them of us and say
>   *For their tomorrow we gave our today.*
>   (Allied war memorial at Kohima)

Here is one such example,

> "The beggarly Jewish radicals of the 30's are now the ruling cultural pundits of American society -- I who stood so long outside the door wondering if I would ever get through it, am now one of the standard-bearers of American literary opinion -- a judge to young men."
>   <sub>--Kazin, Alfred. *The Passionate Encounter: In 65 years of keeping a journal, a noted midcentury critic had much to say about his fellow writers and the literary world they shared.*</sub>

Comment: Yes, I would mark this as a literary usage; a way to make something sound formal or important, or add effect. I also agree with what you said in your comment on the question (which I think you should add to your answer!) that there's a difference between watched/watching. There's also the distinction between two definitions of watched: does the OP mean they were *minding* the children, or just *observing* them? This question is a bit more complicated than one would think! Anyway, +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

It is very unusual to use *who* with the first person, but the word *while* would work.

> While [I was] sitting on the bridge, I watched the children.

The *I was* is optional.